# Jackson serialized list does not contain subtype type property

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to serialize a list of objects (which are subclasses) using Jackson but I can't get Jackson to serialize the type-info-property.

This is the essence of my code:

```
// Superclass A that instructs Jackson to include a type property in the serialized json string 
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true, defaultImpl = A.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "B", value = B.class)
})
class A {
    String type;
}

// The subclass. I expect this to be serialized with a type="B" property
class B extends class A {
    List<Something> list;
}

// A (pagination) container that I use
class GenericContainer<T> {
    List<T> content;
}

// required to avoid type erasure
class ContainerOfB extends GenericContainer<B>
```

When I serialize something like this

```
new ContainerOfB(new B())
```

the output looks like this

```
{
   "content" : [
        {
            // Does not contain the type property
            "list": [...]
        }
    ]
}
```

The type property is not present in the output

I'm not sure what I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you give us a complete and reproducible example?

Comment: With a few adjustments (adding appropriate getters and/or `@JsonProperty` annotations), this works fine for me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I guess I've simplified a bit too much. When I try this example myself, it works indeed. Going to investigate further on my main project. Thanks and apologies for not trying the simplified version myself.

Comment: Ok .. found it. I was using jackson 1.x in the project defining the objects and 2.x in the project that actually serializes them. Since they changed packagenames between the versions, the 2.x serializer didn't pick up the @JsonTypeInfo from 1.x.