# Jackson serializer doesn't show jsonInfoType after serializing

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a base class and a derived class like below

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,
include =JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "_type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BaseClass.class,
name = "BaseClass")})    
public class BaseClass{
    private String a;
}


public class DerivedClass extends BaseClass{
    private String b;
}
```

When I serialize List of BaseClass or List of DerivedClass I couldn't find '_type' property in my json. But if I serialize a single instance of BaseClass or Derived class I can see '_type' property.

Here is my Serializer code.

```
public void serialize() throws Exception {

    List<DerivedClass> bs = new ArrayList<DerivedClass>();
    bs.add(new DerivedClass());
    bs.add(new DerivedClass());
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bs);
    LOG.debug(json);
}
```

Comment: I tried all the solution on stack overflow. Looks Iike I a doing similar stuff but not sure why I couldn't get type. I don't want to use mapper.writerWithType().

Comment: This is not enough to reproduce your problem: please include code you use for serialization. There are common problems, such as trying serialize a `List` of polymorphic values, where Java Type Erasure causes problems. But without code it is impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: @StaxMan I have added code to serialize it.

Comment: [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567131/jackson-serialized-list-does-not-contain-subtype-type-property) This is exactly my scenario. @StaxMan

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that due to Java Type Erasure, all Jackson sees is `List<Object>`, regarding type. Since `Object` has no `@JsonTypeInfo`, it does not think type information is needed -- all values MUST use same logical base type, because during deserialization there are no instances, and statically known typing must be used as baseline.

So how do you resolve this?

First: my suggestion is to ALWAYS use a simple, non-generic POJO as the root value, and avoid the problem altogether. Any `List` valued properties reached from POJO will have full type information; root values do not. As such, I avoid directly serializing `List`s and `Map`s, as well as generic (parameterized) POJOs.

However, should you still want to solve the harder problem, it is doable as well. Two main ways:

First approach: create a convenience class, like:

```
public class ListOfBase extends ArrayList<BaseClass> { }
ListOfBase myList = new ListOfBase();
myList.add(...);
```

and it will work as expected, with type information

Second approach: force use of specific base type, via `ObjectWriter`: something like:

```
ObjectWriter w = mapper.writerFor(new TypeReference<List<BaseClass>>() { });
String json = w.writeValueAsString(myList);
```

But this will (unfortunately) also force use of `BaseClass` for actual contents, not just type info. So any properties implementing classes may have are NOT included.

Actually, there is also third choice: use Java arrays, not collections.
Arrays are strongly typed, so this will also work:

```
BaseClass[] stuff = new BaseClass[] { value1, value2 };
```

since type information is retained, unlike with generic `List`s.

Comment: Does this work if I say
List<BaseClass> list = new ArrayList<BaseClass>();

Comment: No: Type Erasure means that Java has no concept of runtime generic types; only `Class` declarations contain them. This is why `TypeReference` works: it creates actual anonymous class which contains type declarations. Mere instantiation does not retain additional type information: underlying physical class is the same `ArrayList`, which is generic itself and actual type parameters are lost (they only exist in source, bytecode just contains casts necessary).